# Firebase upload listeners never get fired

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am building an android application that uploads photos from a device to a Firebase storage. The images are properly uploaded but I can't get the upload listeners to work. I have gone through the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files) and implemented the exact same solution:

```
System.out.println("Starting upload");
Uri file = Uri.fromFile(new File("myPath"));
StorageReference Ref = storageRef.child("images/"+file.getLastPathSegment());
uploadTask = Ref.putFile(file);

// Register observers to listen for when the download is done or if it fails
uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
        // NEVER EXECUTES
           System.out.println("upload failed");

    }
}).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
        // NEVER EXECUTES
           System.out.println("upload succeeded");
    }
});
```

I can see the first line printed "Starting upload". But that's it. The same goes for OnCompleteListener if I add it but it's omitted here.

What is going wrong?

Comment: Use Log.d("TAG", "Successful/Failure") and see if that prints.

Comment: Or run in debug mode and add breakpoint inside listeners

Comment: you should add the listeners before you start to upload the file path. It's just tooo damn fast

Comment: @Blundell it is "hard" to believe for 2 assignment statements to have taken more time than a file upload...

Comment: @ZohaibAmir that's not technically correct. I'd say you mean "It's hard to believe the file upload completed before the next 2 assignment statements executed". However we can't see the source, and maybe the first line inside the 'file upload api' checks for listeners, therefore (because we don't know) best practice would say to set the listeners first

Comment: @ZohaibAmir Thanks for the reply. I have tried that, however, the breakpoints inside the listeners never get hit, because the listeners never get fired ...

Comment: @Blundell Thanks for your suggestion. I am not able to add the listeners before calling the upload method. uploadTask get instantiated when I call Ref.putFile(). There is no constructor - as fat as I know - for the upload task. Placing listeners ahead of the call will throw a Null Reference exception ...

Answer (score 0):

Try OnCompleteListener

```
uploadTask = Ref.putFile(file);
uploadTask.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            System.out.println("upload succeeded");
        } else {
            System.out.println("upload failed");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks man. uploadTask.addOnCompleteListener takes a listener of a different type: OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>, not a <Uri> type, unless I am missing something. Adding the latter has the same issue (never gets fired and breakpoints never get hit) ...